# Regular Expression to parse group of strings with quotes separated by space

Tags: regex

Given a line of string that does not have any linebreak, I want to get groups of strings which may consist of quotes and separated by space. Space is allowed only if it's within quotes. E.g.

a="1234" gg  b=5678  c="1 2 3"

The result should have 4 groups:

1. a="1234"
2. gg
3. b=5678
4. c="1 2 3"

So far I have this

`/[^\s]+(=".*?"|=".*?[^s]+|=[^\s]+|=)/g`

but this cannot capture the second group "gg". I can't check if there is space before and after the text, as this will include the string that has space within quotes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**Edited**
This is for javascript

Comment: Try [`\w+(?:=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\d+)))?`](https://regex101.com/r/GQcE51/3)

Comment: Are you working in PHP?

Comment: it's in javascript

Comment: Try [the `\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\d+))?` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQcE51/4). Also, see [this JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8crua33L/)

Comment: It looks good, but it can be b=abcd, which does not capture

Comment: Try then [`\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\S+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/GQcE51/5), see [this JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8crua33L/2/).

Comment: You are quick! Is it possible to also include '='? for example: 
`a="aa" bb= cc="fffaa" bbc=5aaa `. `bb=` should be captured too

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917036/3832970), please check below and consider accepting if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you may use the following regex:

```
/\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)?)?/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQcE51/6).

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1+ letters, digits or/and `_`
- `(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `=` - an equal sign
  - `(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, then 0+ chars other than `"` and then `"`
    - `|` - or
    - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)?)?/g;
var s = 'a="1234" gg  b=5678  c="1 2 3" d=abcd e=';
console.log(s.match(rx));
```

Answer (score 0):

if I did not misunderstand what you are saying this is what you are looking for.

```
\w+=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\d+))|(?|[a-z]+)
```

think of the or works as a fallback option there for use more complex one in front of the more generic ones.

alternatively, you can remove second `?|` and it will capture it as a different group so you can check that group (group 2)